# Converting a 19 digits time stamp to a real time (from .zvi file format)

Tags: datetime, metadata

After a long day of research,
Is anybody knows how to convert a 19 digits time stamp from the metadata of .zvi file (produce by axiovision, Zeiss) to a real time format ?  (The output probably includes milliseconds)

An example time-stamp is: 4675873294709522577

Thanks !

Arnon

Answer (score 2):

Matlab solution:

The main issue is not the x2mdate conversion (which simply adds the number of days between the year zero, when Matlab starts counting, and the year 1900, when Excel/zvi starts counting), but the same class issue as described above. This conversion to double can be done with typecast in Matlab:

```
myZVI = 4675946358764751269;
timestampDouble = typecast(int64(myZVI),'double');
myTime = datestr(timestampDouble + 693960, 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS.FFF');
```

693960 is the number of days between year zero and 1900; if you don't need an absolute date but just the difference between two timestamps, you don't even need this; for instance the interval between two of my video frames can be calculated like this:

```
myZVI2 = 4675946358764826427;
timestampDouble2 = typecast(int64(myZVI2),'double');
myTimeDifference = datestr(timestampDouble2 - timestampDouble,'SS.FFF');
```

hope this helps:-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Microsoft OLE Automation Date.  But you've read it as a 64-bit long integer instead of the 64-bit double that it should be.

You didn't specify a language, so I will pick C#:

```cs
long l = 4675873294709522577L;
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(l);
double d = BitConverter.ToDouble(b, 0);
Debug.WriteLine(d);  // 41039.901598693

DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
Debug.WriteLine(dt);  // 5/10/2012 9:38:18 PM
```

More information in [this thread](http://www.openmicroscopy.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=5977).

An OLE Automation Date is basically the number of whole 24-hour days since 1/1/1900 without any particular time zone reference.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Do you know how to do the same conversion under matlab?

Comment: I'm not a matlab user, but I would guess from the docs that [`x2mdate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/x2mdate.html) could be used for the second part.